# ¿Como validar numeros de tarjetas de crédito o débito con espacios?

Tags: javascript, regex

Veran estoy intento validar números de tarjetas de crédito/débito pero con espacios en cada 3 o 4 números.
Digamos que tengo este numero de tarjeta de crédito/débito que incluye tres espacios como delimitadores:

```
 // american express => patrón [4,6,5]
3400[]000000[]00009
 // discover => patrón [4,4,4,4] 
6011[]0000[]0000[]0004
// mastercard => patrón [4,4,4,4]
5500[]0000[]0000[]0004
// visa => patrón [4,4,4,4]
4111[]1111[]1111[]1111
// los corchetes son representaciónes de un espacio dependiendo del patrón asignado
```

añadi unos patrones en forma de array, en el caso de American Express el patrón es, los primero 4 dígitos los separo con un espacio seguido de los siguientes 6 dígitos con espacio seguido de los últimos 5 dígitos.

En el caso de Discover, MasterCard y Visa el patrón es cada 4 dígitos separados con un espacio seguido de los siguientes 4 y así hasta llegar a los últimos cuatro dígitos.
Tal y como muestro arriba.

El regex múltiple solo valida de esta forma:

```
// american expresa
 340000000000009
 // discover
6011000000000004
// mastercard
5500 0000 0000 0004
// visa
4111111111111111
```

Esta función valida los números de tarjetas con espacios como delimitadores entre cada 3 o 4 numeros, dependiendo del tipo de tarjeta. En este caso valido 4 tipos de tarjetas en un solo regex que son American Express, Discover, MasterCard y Visa

```
function validCard(input) {
    var valid;
    var regex = /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|3[47][0-9]{13}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12})$/;
    if (regex.test(input)) {
        valid = true;
    } else {
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
var input = "4111 1111 1111 1111";
valid card(input); // return false
```

También use el regex que recomendó @Ali pero añadiento un or para validar los dígitos de la tarjeta amex

```
var regex = /^(?:(\d{4}\s?){4}|(\d{4,6}\s?){3})$/
```

Comment: sería bueno indicar qué casos son buenos y cuáles no. Por ejemplo, ¿debe haber siempre 16 dígitos? ¿Los espacios, si aparecen, deben hacerlo entre todos los bloques de 3 o 4? Es decir, un patrón claro de casuísticas para poder "jugar" con ellos.

Comment: no me refiero a qué produce tu código actual, sino a qué debe hacer el código que lo resuelva. Esto es, proporciona un [mcve]. Estás asumiendo que todo el mundo sabe que un número de tarjeta de crédito tiene 16 caracteres, sin indicarlo en ningún punto :)

Comment: Mencionas espacios cada 3 dígitos, pero son 16 dígitos.

Comment: sigo sin ver explicación alguna del patrón que estás buscando. Supongo que estarás cansado, porque eres un usuario que sabe preguntar, pero es que esta pregunta es un poco caos :P Piensa "si quiero hacerlo, antes debo poder explicarlo"

Comment: @fedorqui añadí mas detalles, incluí algunos patrones intentando ser los mas entendible posible

Comment: @RimuruTempest, no sería más sencillo remplazar todos los espacios antes de hacer el regex?

Comment: Ya lo había pensado @Ali pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: Lo de reemplazar los espacios si, pero lo del regex no xd

Comment: Para remplazar los espacios se puede hacer con `'1234 1234'.split(' ').join('')` y luego aplicar el regex, de todas formas he actualizado mi respuesta para hacerlo solo con regex.

Comment: Gracias @Ali me diste una idea brillante. Al momento de validar la tarjeta de crédito reemplace todos los espacios de esta form `replace(/\s/g, "")` y ahora el regex que puse haya arriba funciona correctamente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podemos hacerlo de usando {} para cantidades específicas:

```
[0-9]{15,16}|(([0-9]{4}\s){3}[0-9]{3,4})
```

- `[0-9]{15,16}`: Indica un número de 15 o 16 dígitos
- `|`: Indica "O"
- `()`: Utilizamos paréntesis para agrupar la siguiente expresión.
- `[0-9]{4}\s`: 4 dígitos seguidos de espacio
- `([0-9]{4}\s){3}`: 4 dígitos seguidos de espacio, 3 veces
- `[0-9]{3,4}`: Solo 3 o 4 dígitos.

```js
var regex = /^[0-9]{15,16}|(([0-9]{4}\s){3}[0-9]{3,4})$/; // 16 digitos o de 4 en 4 separados por espacios.

function validate() {
 result.innerHTML = regex.test(input.value) ? 'ok' : 'fail';
}
validate();
document.addEventListener('keyup', validate);
```

```html
<input id="input" autocomplete=off value="1234 1234 1234 1234">
<span id="result">
```

Y si no te quieres exigir que tenga siempre espacios cada 4 dígitos o sea permitir algo como `0000 00000000000000` la cosa se vuelve más fácil

```
([0-9]{4}\s?){4}
```

Con lo cual decimos (4 dígitos seguidos opcionalmente por un espacio) 4 veces.

**Edición:**

Antes de que editaras tu pregunta tenías un formato que terminaba con 3 dígitos y ahora uno que termina con 5 dígitos, si no importa donde está el espacio, puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
(\d\s?){15,16}
```

- `\d`: Especifica un solo dígito al igual que [0-9]
- `\s?`: Especifica un espacio de forma opcional
- `(\d\s?)`: Es un dígito que puede estar seguido o no de un espacio
- `{15,16}`: Solo pueden haber 15 o 16 dígitos con espacio.

```js
var regex = /^(\d\s?){15,16}$/; // 16 digitos o de 4 en 4 separados por espacios.

function validate() {
 result.innerHTML = regex.test(input.value) ? 'ok' : 'fail';
}
validate();
document.addEventListener('keyup', validate);
```

```html
<input id="input" autocomplete=off value="1234 1234 1234 1234">
<span id="result">
```

Comment: Hola! Un placer, tal vez me puedes sacar de la duda. Queria preguntar ¿cómo puedo validar que no permita tarjetas AMEX?

Comment: Hola, según https://blog.unibulmerchantservices.com/10-signs-of-a-valid-american-express-card/ tendrías que validar que no empiece con 37 o 34 o más sencillo, que empiece con 4 para que solo sean las visa: `4[0-9]{3}\s(([0-9]{4}\s){2}[0-9]{4})`

Answer (score 2):

Si te interesase validar que los espacios estén en posiciones concretas, prueba a utilizar esta expresión regular.

```
^(?:\d{15,16}|\d{4}(?:(?:\s+\d{4}){3}|\s+\d{6}\s\d{5}))$
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/KV8q7r/5/)

Así pues, validaría cosas como:

```
3400 000000 00009
4111 1111 1111 1111
4111111111111111
```

Pero no otros números con formato incorrecto como:

```
41 111 11111111111
3400 0000 00 00009
3 4 00 0000 00 00009
4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder, el formato era el que tenia incorrecto, salvaste mi vida! Gracias